# Actualización en tiempo real al trasladar información de un data gridview a otro en formularios diferentes c#

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes con toda la comunidad.
Disculpen ayer no realice la pregunta adecuadamente por lo que lo edito para que me puedan entenderme mejor. Espero puedan ayudar y agradezco a quienes hasta el momento trataron de ayudarme.

CONSULTA:

1. Se tiene el siguiente Formulario1.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Formulario2 Hijo del cual mediante el evento doble_click se quiere transferir los datos hacia el dgvPresupuesto y que este se actualice automaticamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Bien lo que intentado hasta el momento es lo Siguiente:

   CODIGO DEL FORMULARIO1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CODIGO DEL FORMULARIO2 HIJO:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien el problema que deseo solucionar el que al momento de darle doble_click en el dgv.PartidasEdicion no se actualiza el dgvPresupuesto, menciono que guarda los datos correctamente, por lo que el unico problema seria que no se actualiza en tiempo real.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: y porque simplemente las dos grillas no apuntan al mismo objeto que las llena?? o como las llenas??? esto es winforms o wpf?

Comment: EL datagridview2 se llena mediante un procedimiento almacenado que hice en Sql Server a partir de la tabla1 y el datagridview2 se llena de igual manera pero con otro procedimiento alamcenado a partir de otra tabla (Tabla2) que contiene la informacion que se va guardando al darle doble_click en el Datagridview1

Comment: no pregunte eso, si no que objetos estan asociados al llenado de cada grilla

Comment: puedes agregar imágenes  de como tienes estructurado tus formularios, y código de como llenas los grids, para entenderte mejor

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar, porque tu pregunta tiene una respuesta simple. Como conectas tu grilla a los datos? usas un objeto? usas un dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Mi respuesta se basa en lo que entendí de tu planteamiento el cual resumí de la siguiente manera:

*Se tiene una instancia del `Form2` que fue creada dentro del `Form1` y el requerimiento es que cierta actividad en el `Form2` sea reportada al `Form1`.*

Una de las soluciones que se me ocurren implica lo siguiente:

- Declarar un evento en `Form2` que será disparado desde el doble_click en el datagridview2.
- Suscribirse al evento después de crear la instancia en `Form1`
- Ejecutar el método `metodoMostrar1()` dentro del manejador del evento.

**Creación del evento en `Form2`**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    // Declaro el evento
    public event EventHandler DatosGuardados;
    // Y el método que lo dispara
    protected virtual void OnDatosGuardados(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DatosGuardados?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    //...

    
    private void metodoGuardado1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Aqui tengo el codigo que guarda la informacion selecionada en la Base de Datos.

        //Aquí dispara el evento para notificar que se guardaron datos
        OnDatosGuardados(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    }
}
```

**Manejo del evento en `Form1`**

Luego en `Form1` voy a suponer que la instancia de `Form2` es creada en el constructor para este ejemplo, ten el cuenta que el lugar donde se crea es irrelevante, lo que importa en realidad es la suscripción al evento después de crear la instancia.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    //Declaro la variable para la instancia de Form2
    Form form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Crear la instancia
        form2 = new Form2();
        // Suscribirse al evento
        form2.DatosGuardados += Form2_DatosGuardados;
    }

    // Y en el método que maneja el evento

    private void Form2_DatosGuardados(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        metodoMostrar1();
    }


    // Sugiero que este método lo hagas privado
    private void metodoMostrar1() //Metodo utilizado para llenar el dgv1
    {
        // Aqui tengo el Codigo que llena el dgv1
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, intente realizarlo pero no me funciono, edite la pregunta para que puedan entenderme mejor, espero puedas ayudarme..

Comment: @FreddySánchez, en las imagenes del código que publicaste, no se ve como abres o muestras la instancia del formulario que llamas hijo. Además sospecho que no es el mismo que la instancia que creaste basandote en mi respuesta (form2). Para que el código de mi respuesta funcione, la suscripción al evento tienes que hacerla en la misma instancia que estás mostrando.