# ¿Cómo realizar comunicación entre formularios?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

Tengo un programa que tiene como un mainform y desde ahí se van llamando a otros forms hijos. Los forms se abren dentro de un Panel, utilizando el siguiente método:

```
private void AbrirFormHijo(object formHijo)
{
    if (this.pnlForms.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
       this.pnlForms.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    Form fh = formHijo as Form;
    fh.TopLevel = false;
    fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.pnlForms.Controls.Add(fh);
    this.pnlForms.Tag = fh;
    fh.Show();            
}
```

Después llamó a ese método para abrir cada form de esta manera:

```
AbrirFormHijo(formHijo: new FormXXXX());
```

El programa es basicamente para registrar cuentas personales, gastos, sueldo, y todo lo que tenga que ver con el manejo de dinero.
Cuando registro cada movimiento, en el main form tengo un label que tiene que ir actualizándose, dependiendo de cada movimiento nuevo que se ingrese (restar, sumar y así).

El problema es que no puedo hacer que se actualice el label del mainform cada vez que registro un movimiento nuevo.

Quise crear una clase que fuera pública para toda la capa de presentación, pero cuando instancio el mainform en la clase y luego instancio la clase en el form, me da un error de redundancia y me deja sin memoria al ejecutar. Ya intenté inclusive poniendo el label con modificador público, aunque no sea buena práctica, pero solo se actualiza una vez que salgo del form donde registro cada movimiento.

**¿Alguna idea de cómo resolver esto?**

Comment: Hola Joel,[En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/393973/182188) describo un procedimiento para manejarlo utilizando eventos y [en esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/373058/182188) describo un procedimiento utilizando interfaces. No son respuestas específicas a tu caso, pero basicamente tratan la comunicacion entre formularios "hijos" con su formulario creador

Comment: Manejando eventos no funciona. Voy a probar con una interface y te digo si me funciona. Se que no probé todo, pero hay muchas soluciones que he visto en otros foros, videos, etc, pero ninguno funciona como pretendo

Comment: Hola Joel, de acuerdo con lo que entendí de tu pregunta, los eventos deberían funcionar. Sin embargo el planteamiento me da la impresión de que son varios formularios hijos y me parece que utilizar la interface sería más sencillo de implementar.

Comment: Son varios forms hijos, pero solo 1 es el que realiza el cambio que necesito

Comment: Ah ok, me puedes dar detalles de los datos que necesitas del formulario hijo para actualizar en el padre? Es un monto o una clase o estructura más compleja.

Comment: El form padre solicita el resultado de la suma de cada dato agregado desde el form hijo. Cuando agrego un nuevo dato desde el form hijo, tambien necesito que actualice el form padre, xq la suma cambia, y eso es lo que no logro solucionar.

Comment: Joel, está mañana escribi una respuesta. Por favor revísala y avísame cualquier duda o si requieres alguna aclaratoria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con base en los comentarios que intercambiamos, mi sugerencia es crear un evento en el formulario hijo que notifique el cambio que necesitas.

Para que funcione, será necesario lo siguiente:

- Crear una clase que contenga todas las propiedades que necesites enviar desde el formulario hijo al padre. Esta clase debe heredar de `EventArgs`.
- Declarar el evento en el formulario hijo que será disparado en el punto que consideres apropiado.
- En el formulario padre, te suscribes al evento después de crear la instancia del formulario hijo.
- Dentro del manejador del evento, ejecutar la lógica de la actualización.

#### Clase de ejemplo para enviar los datos

```
// Modifica esta clase con todas las propiedades necesarias
// para que el formulario hijo le envíe al padre.
// Y por supuesto ponle un nombre que tenga sentido en el contexto
// de tu aplicación
public class DatosParaActualizarEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public string TextoDeEjemplo { get; set; }
    public decimal MontoDeEjemplo { get; set; }
}
```

#### Declaración del evento y el método que lo dispara en el formulario hijo

```
public partial class FormularioHijoConEvento: Form
{
    // Esta es la declaración del evento
    // Ten en cuenta que esta es la clase declarada en el paso anterior
    //                         |
    //                         V
    public event EventHandler<DatosParaActualizarEventArgs> NotificarCambios;

    // Este es el método que se usa para disparar el evento (también conocido como trigger)
    protected virtual void OnNotificarCambios(object sender, DatosParaActualizarEventArgs e)
    {
        NotificarCambios?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    // el resto del código del formulario ...
}
```

Ahora el formulario hijo debe diaparar el evento. El siguiente código, debes colocarlo en el formulario hijo, justo en el punto donde quisieras decirle al formulario padre que se actualice.

```
        // Primero creas la instancia con toda la información que enviarás al padre
        var datosDelEvento = new DatosParaActualizarEventArgs()
        {
            TextoDeEjemplo = "Un nuevo gasto registrado",
            MontoDeEjemplo = 73
        };

        // Y luego disparas el evento
        OnNotificarCambios(this, datosDelEvento);
```

#### Manejo del evento en el formulario Padre

Será necesario modificar la línea `AbrirFormHijo(formHijo: new FormXXXX());` porque necesitas una referencia a la instancia creada para poder suscribirte al evento:

```
    // Crear la instancia
    var hijoConEvento = new FormularioHijoConEvento();
    // Suscripción al evento
    hijoConEvento.NotificarCambios += formHijo_NotificarCambios;
    
    AbrirFormHijo(formHijo: hijoConEvento);
```

Finalmente en el método manejador del evento, ejecutas la lógica de actualización, por ejemplo:

```
    private void formHijo_NotificarCambios(object sender, DatosParaActualizarEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = e.TextoDeEjemplo;
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Ahora empiezo a hacerla y en estos dias te respondo a ver si me funciona.

Comment: Sos un crack. Muy bien explicado la verdad. Me funcionó de 10, Hace lo que quiero y me sirve para otras actualizaciones que necesito hacer en tiempo real. Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Una solución a tu problema podría ser que pasaras a cada Form hijo el formulario `Main` como parámetro, de esta manera tendrías acceso a sus controles públicos y podrías modificar el contenido del formulario `Main` desde cualquier hijo.

Simplemente en el `New` de cada formulario hijo del `Main` pasale un argumento del tipo del formulario `Main`, algo similar a esto:

```
private FormMain frmMain;
public formHijo(FormMain frm)
{
    frmMain = frm;
}
```

De esta manera podrías hacer algo así:

```
frmMain.Label1.Text = "Texto puesto desde un hijo";
```

Comment: Perdón mi ignorancia, pero Me decís que tengo agregar ese código que me pasaste, quedando así:
´private void AbrirFormHijo(object formHijo, FormInicio frm)
        {
            mainForm = frm;
            if (this.pnlForms.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                this.pnlForms.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            Form fh = formHijo as Form;
            fh.TopLevel = false;
            fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.pnlForms.Controls.Add(fh);
            this.pnlForms.Tag = fh;
            fh.Show();            
        }´

Comment: y luego cuando llamo al label desde el formhijo, tengo que instanciar al mainform de manera normal? es decir.. MainForm_mainForm = new MainForm();
_mainForm.LabenXXX.Text = "blabla" así?

Comment: Tu Main Form ya estará instanciado porque vas a llamar el Form hijo desde él, simplemente cuando llames al frm Hijo, pasale por parametro tu form Main (algo tipo `FormHijo frm = new FormHijo(this)`

Comment: Lo probé péro no hace nada. :'(