# doublepasar datos de control de usuario a datagridview en el formulario principal

Tags: c#, visual-studio

``ESTOY TRABAJANDO CON USERCONTROL POR PRIMERA VEZ.
MI CASO ES: Tengo 1 **USERCONTROL** en un Formulario (**FORM1**), donde **USERCONTROL1** contiene varios Textbox y en el **Form1** contiene una vista de cuadrícula de datos. Si puede ayudarme con el caso,
¿cómo puedo pasar los datos del cuadro de texto a la vista de cuadrícula de datos?
Y si puede cargar los datos de la vista de cuadrícula de datos al Texbox seleccionando una fila de la vista de cuadrícula de datos. Gracias por adelantado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentando de varias forma y no he tenido ningun resuktado, esto es lo ultimo que he intentado
en el
**FORM1**

```
namespace Proyecto

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 UC1= new UserControl1 ();
        UserControl2 UC2= new UserControl2 ();

        UC1.Tag = UC2;
        UC2.Tag = UC1;
    }
}
```

**USERCONTROL1** Contiene los textbox

```
public partial class USERCONTROL1: UserControl
{

    internal class Persona
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public double Precio { get; set; }
    }

    public USERCONTROL1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal Persona CurentPersona
    {
        get
        {
            return new Persona()
            {
                Nombre = txtNombre.Text,
                Precio = txtPrecio.Text,
            };
        }
        set
        {
            txtNombre.Text = value == null ? string.Empty : value.Nombre;
            txtPrecio.Text = value == null ? string.Empty : value.Precio;
        }
    }

    private void btnEntrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

**USERCONTROL2** Contiene el Datagridview

```
public USERCONTROL2()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void USERCONTROL2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvContenido.Rows.Add("Limon", "10");
        dgvContenido.Rows.Add("Naranja", "20");
        dgvContenido.Rows.Add("Guineo", "22");

    }

    private void dgvContenido_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name != "EditColumn") return;

        var rowToEdit = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        var dialog = new DialogForm
        {
            CurentPersona = new Persona()
            {
                Nombre = (string)rowToEdit.Cells["NombreColumn"].Value,
                Precio = (double)rowToEdit.Cells["PrecioColumn"].Value,

            }
        };

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            rowToEdit.Cells["NombreColumn"].Value = dialog.CurentPersona.Nombre;
            rowToEdit.Cells["PrecioColumn"].Value = dialog.CurentPersona.Precio;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tienes esta misma pregunta 2 veces. Mi sugerencia es que mantengas una sola, agrega nueva información o código que hayas investigado/intentado. Te sugiero leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/396454/182188) , la lógica que allí se explica la puedes adaptar para obtener el resultado que esperas.

Comment: en verdad soy muy nuevo en esta parte de los UserControl, pero me interesa ya que para diseñar lo veo mas cómodo