# Pasar datos entre Formularios abiertos C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Actualizo mi pregunta con un ejemplo que cree nuevo
en el Form1 que el el principal tengo un label1,
que es donde voy a tener todas las repuestas, un control de usuario que cree el cual contiene un cuadro de texto y botón, y en la parte inferior izquierda un botón, el cual me llama al FormHijo. lo que escribo en la caja de texto del control de usuario me lo presenta en el label1, aquí todo va bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    public partial class FrmPrincipal : Form
    {
        public FrmPrincipal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var hijoConEvento = new FrmHijo();
            AbrirFormHijo(formHijo: hijoConEvento);

            userControl11.NotificarCambios += formHijo_NotificarCambios;

            //Form3 se abre desde el panel en el FrmHijo
            //aqui no me funciona, igual si lo coloco en el boton
            var form3 = new Form3();
            form3.NotificarCambios += formHijo_NotificarCambios;

            //UserControl2 se abre desde el panel en el FrmHijo
            //aqui no me funciona, igual si lo coloco en el boton
            var UC2 = new UserControl2();
            UC2.NotificarCambios += formHijo_NotificarCambios;

        }

        private void AbrirFormHijo(FrmHijo formHijo)
        {
        }

        private void formHijo_NotificarCambios(object sender, DatosEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = e.NombreText;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrmHijo frmhijo = new FrmHijo();
            frmhijo.NotificarCambios += formHijo_NotificarCambios;
            frmhijo.Show();

           frmhijo.userControl11.NotificarCambios += formHijo_NotificarCambios;

        }

    }
}
```

Al abrir el FormHijo en este tengo 4 opciones, 1_ una caja de texto y un botón, 2_ UserControl1 (contiene una caja de texto y un botón),3_ 1 botón y un panel igual la opción 4, el botón sobre el panel a la izquierda llama al Form3 (contiene una caja de texto y un botón) y el botón a la derecha sobre el panel, abre en ese panel el UserControl2 (contiene una caja de texto y un botón).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que escribo en el *texbox* y pulso el botón me lo presenta en el label1 del formulario principal, igual si escribo en el UserControl1, hasta ahí todo marcha bien, el problema aquí, cuando llamo al Form3 o el UserControl2 en los paneles, al escribir al igual que en los dos casos de arriba, no me presenta nada.

```
    public partial class FrmHijo : Form
    {

        public event EventHandler<DatosEventArgs> NotificarCambios;

        public FrmHijo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected virtual void OnNotificarCambios(object sender, DatosEventArgs e)
        {
            NotificarCambios?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }

        private void btnEntrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var datosEvento = new DatosEventArgs()
            {
                NombreText = textBox1.Text
            };

            OnNotificarCambios(this, datosEvento);
        }

        //METODO PARA ABRIR Formulario en el Panel 
        private Form formActivado = null;

        private void AbrirFormularioPanel(Form FormHijo)
        {
            if (formActivado != null)
                formActivado.Close();
            formActivado = FormHijo;
            FormHijo.TopLevel = false;
            FormHijo.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pnlFrmulario.Controls.Add(FormHijo);
            pnlFrmulario.Tag = FormHijo;
            FormHijo.BringToFront();
            FormHijo.Show();
        }

        //ABRIR FORMULARIO EN PANEL
        private void btnFormPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             AbrirFormularioPanel(new Form3());
        }

        //ABRIR CONTROL DE USUARIO EN PANEL 
        private void btnUCPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl2 UC2 = new UserControl2();
            UC2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pnlGeneral.Controls.Clear();
            pnlGeneral.Controls.Add(UC2);
        }
    }
}
```

Tanto el Form3 como el UserControl2 tiene la misma estructura que el *UserControl1*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {

        public event EventHandler<DatosEventArgs> NotificarCambios;

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected virtual void OnNotificarCambios(object sender, DatosEventArgs e)
        {
            NotificarCambios?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }


        private void btnEntrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var datosDelEvento = new DatosEventArgs()
            {
                NombreText = textBox1.Text

            };

            OnNotificarCambios(this, datosDelEvento);
        }

        private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mostra como haces para pasar de 1 a 2, porque es exactamente lo mismo...

Comment: Hola, @gbianchi gracias por responder, pase el código y una explicación mas clara de lo que quiero, ver si me puede ayudar

Comment: en realidad el interés principal es poder pasar los datos desde el formulario abierto en el panel, el otro botón lo puse a manera de ejemplo

Comment: No termino de entender tu escenario y tu problema.. tu formulario hijo, que no puede ser hijo de otro formulario (por como funcionan los formularios) seria formActivado...

Comment: En [está respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/396454/182188), trato una manera de comunicar formularios utilizando eventos. En mi opinión, puedes resolver tu requerimiento con los conceptos allí explicados.

Comment: hola, @PabloGutiérrez, gbianchi, David Con.....PabloGutiérrez tu enlace me ha sido de mucha ayuda, pero creo que no me he sabido explicar, aquí voy a dejar esta ruta donde tengo un pequeño ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer, tengo varias opciones donde me funcionan 3 pero hay 2 que no, ver si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: aqui el proyecto de ejemplo [https://mega.nz/file/MptS3LKJ#Jt6YNTGhya_LpMRDNqjs0Kq1aSunaHAgKOhm66gpot0]

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por tu ayuda, valoro tu esfuerzo, pero en verdad tengo mucho tiempo queriendo resolver este problema y he leído mucho sobre el tema pero no se donde esta mi gran error si puede echar un vistazo a este pequeño proyecto [https://mega.nz/file/MptS3LKJ#Jt6YNTGhya_LpMRDNqjs0Kq1aSunaHAgKOhm66gpot0]

Comment: No.. no puedo ver tu proyecto. Te pediria por favor que agregaras un [mcve] a tu pregunta para que podamos replicar tu escenario.. como te escribi antes, no me queda claro que tratas de hacer...

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por la sugerencia, reedite el ejemplo que hice y lo pase aquí, para cuando pueda le eche un vistazo, gracias de antemano

Comment: pero vos le queres pasar datos a otro form o a un user control? son cosas distintas...

Comment: si se que son distinta, pero lo puse a modo de ejemplo por eso abro un usercontrol en un panel y un form3 en el otro

Comment: Pude reproducir parte del ejemplo con base en el código y tus comentarios. No voy a elaborar una respuesta porque sería repetir [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395389/c%c3%b3mo-realizar-comunicaci%c3%b3n-entre-formularios/396454#396454). Tu problema es que estás anidando formularios y para que eso funcione, dentro de `frnhijo` tienes que atrapar los eventos de `UC2` y `form3` y reenviarlos mediante `OnNotificarCambios`. Si me permites una sugerencia, considera evaluar un enfoque diferente porque el que planteas está tan complejo que te puede dar muchos dolores de cabeza.

Answer (score -1):

En el Form2 puedes crear tantas propiedades publicas como necesites y las debes de rellenar con lo el valor que necesites pasar al Form1. Cuando cierres el Form2 tendrás acceso a las propiedades.
Para llamar al Form2 desde el Form1 puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
Form2 miForm2 = new Form2();
if (miForm2.ShowDialog().DialogResult == DialogResults.OK)
{
  miForm2.Propiedad1;
  miForm2.Propiedad2;
  ...
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Esto esta simplemente mal.. el form2 que estas creando ahi, es uno nuevo. OP pregunto explicitamente por formularios que ya estan abiertos.

Comment: Antes de ayer no ponía tanto detalle en la pregunta. Simplemente ponía que tenía dos formularios. Viendo el problema tal y como está descrito, sería mejor usar Eventos en la comunicación como dice Pablo Gutiérrez. Saludos.

Comment: @David Con gracias por tu ayuda, valoro tu esfuerzo, pero en verdad tengo mucho tiempo queriendo resolver este problema y he leído mucho sobre el tema pero no se donde esta mi gran error si puede echar un vistazo a este pequeño proyecto [https://mega.nz/file/MptS3LKJ#Jt6YNTGhya_LpMRDNqjs0Kq1aSunaHAgKOhm66gpot0]