# Ocultar botón al cerrar formulario

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios, botón

Actualmente estoy programando un software pero requiero su ayuda con este tema.

¿Alguien podría indicarme cual seria la codificación para que al cerrar un form se oculte un botón?

Actualmente tengo esta ventana y el botón inscripción esta oculto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de el menustrip / inscripcion

```
        {
            //se localiza el formulario buscandolo entre los forms abiertos 
            Form frm = this.MdiChildren.FirstOrDefault(x => x is inscripcion);

            if (frm != null)
            {
                //si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
                frm.BringToFront();
                return;
            }
            //sino existe la instancia se crea una nueva
            inscripcion AbrirForm = inscripcion.Abrir_inscripcion;
            AbrirForm.MdiParent = this;
            AbrirForm.Show();

            BtnInscripcion.Visible = true;

        }
```

Al darle click en el menú inscripcion se abre la ventana de inscripcion alumno y el botón incripcion aparece.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código del botón Inscripcion es el mismo del menustrip / inscripcion con el objetivo que el botón sea un acceso directo cuando una ventana este abierta y así saber que ventana esta abierta y para pasarla al frente solo le damos click en el botón y no tener que ir hasta el menú abrir la ventana nuevamente.

Pero al cerrar la ventana de inscripcion quiero que el el botón inscripcion se oculte nuevamente.

Resumen: que el botón este abierto solo si el form inscripcion esta activo de lo contrario que se oculte, algo así como:

```
if (frm.inscripcion == active)
    botonInscripcion.visible = true;
else
    botonInscripcion.visible = false;
```

Comment: tendrias que codificar un evento en el formulario hijo que le avise al padre en el momento que se cierra..

Comment: si lo se pero cual seria la codificacin, he intentado hacer un metodo publico pero el metodo no me aparece entre ventanas aunque lo haga publico

Comment: No entiendo que trataste de hacer. Tal vez podrias mostrar lo que intentaste asi te ayudamos desde ese punto?

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/396454/182188) relacionada con comunicación entre formularios basada en eventos te puede servir de guía para lograr el objetivo que te propones.